# (tensorflow) multiply feature map in batch with its feature mean in batch: [n, h, w, c] * [n, c]

Tags: tensorflow

How can I multiply a feature map tensor shaped [n, h, w, c] with its feature mean [n, c] without tiling [n,c] broadcasting in batch?

I am looking for the fastest way.

Unfortunately, tf.multiply does not work. I have two methods: (1) tile the [n,c] tensor, (2) use tf.einsum. But I am quite worried to use them because they might be really slow if I use them in a loop.

----------- I just tried the following---------

```
x = ... # [n,h,w,c]
mean = ... # [n,c]
out = x* tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(mean,1),1)
```

And it worked. Is it a correct solution?

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct, it's simply broadcasting the mean over the h and w dimensions. You can also use `mean[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :]` which is a bit prettier imho.

Comment: `tf.newaxis` wasn't aware of that. `None` like in NumPy works too.